# To Show 24 hours in a day

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to show the 24 hours in a current date eventhough data is not present in the database.

For example, `SELECT TO_CHAR(yoh.createts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS SysHour`, it pulls the hour up to current time, I need full 24 hours even data is not in the database.

If I run this query at 1 PM, it pulls the report from 00,01...13 but I need from 00,01,02,03....22,23.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :  Oracle

Comment: I don't exactly get what you would like to do, but does this give you an idea: `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;`

Answer (score 4):

This hierarchical query shows all hours for current date:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (level-1)/24, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS SysHour
  from dual connect by level <= 24
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1596)</sup>

You'll probably need to `left join` your existing query to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you would like to do, but does this give you an idea: 
 `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;`

Or the date with time: 
`SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY, MONTH DD, HH24:MI:SS') FROM Dual;`

Comment: If you run this query, it gives only current time. SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual.  I need the query to give the result like                                                                                                2015-07-16 00,                                                                                      2015-07-16 01                                                                                     2015-07-16 02      ....................2015-07-16 21, 2015-07-16 22, 2015-07-23

Comment: I think you should look at `SYSDATE`. With that you can ask the database the datum and time, and output them in the way you would like to. Every database (as every computer) knows what date and time it is.